# Sinch js sdk not making calls

Tags: sinch

This is my log i the call always ends with a timeout

I'm using angularjs also so what i'm doing is starting the sinchClient (from a Factory) in the app.js and adding the onIncoming Listener then finally make calls in the controller (from a Factory)

```
GET http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/cordova.js 
i {sinch: f, eventListeners: Array[0], callBuffert: Object, localMediaStream: undefined, incomingCallCustomStream: undefined…}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Get authentication token", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0.2, message: "Get instance using auth token", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0.4, message: "Get MXP configuration", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0.6, message: "Create MXP object", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0.8, message: "Will start active connection", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0.8, message: "Manually starting active connection", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "SinchClient started", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 1, message: "Successfully started SinchClient", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "CallUser method called", object: "brenty"}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Will retrieve new Mic for stream", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Call was muted using mute().", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Call PROGRESSING timeout. Will hangup call.", object: g}message: "Call PROGRESSING timeout. Will hangup call."object: gactiveInstance: undefinedautoAnswer: falseautoHangup: falsecallDomain: "data"callEndCause: 1callId: "bf5d5c3a-9b08-47ed-9275-5d03eb1447ed"callOutbound: truecallState: 3clientMap: Objectvirtual: Objectfs: "29987351-7351-4835-86c1-179ad669a45eS"fu: "brenty"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: __defineGetter__() { [native code] }__defineSetter__: __defineSetter__() { [native code] }__lookupGetter__: __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }__lookupSetter__: __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }constructor: Object() { [native code] }hasOwnProperty: hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }isPrototypeOf: isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }propertyIsEnumerable: propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }toLocaleString: toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: toString() { [native code] }valueOf: valueOf() { [native code] }get __proto__: __proto__() { [native code] }set __proto__: __proto__() { [native code] }customHeaders: Objecttype: "voice"__proto__: ObjectdataChannels: Object__proto__: Objecterror: nulleventListeners: Array[3]0: Object1: Object2: Objectlength: 3__proto__: Array[0]fromId: "triniwiz"hangupRetries: 6iceMapRx: Object__proto__: ObjecticeMapTx: Array[0]length: 0__proto__: Array[0]incomingStream: undefinedincomingStreamURL: undefinedjoinBuffer: Object__proto__: ObjectoutgoingOffer: RTCSessionDescriptionsdp: "v=0
↵o=- 2486728347566751432 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE audio video
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG
↵m=audio 9 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:9XgGQPNJQUYrwuC3
↵a=ice-pwd:7Y30gM1zjN0Vnt5y6IoOoNYD
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 99:E8:0A:BB:55:9A:5F:C6:21:01:06:32:4B:5A:5E:B7:F0:A7:87:49:68:0A:20:4E:5C:AA:ED:66:87:6E:A3:AB
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:audio
↵a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
↵a=fmtp:111 minptime=10; useinbandfec=1
↵a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
↵a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
↵a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
↵a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
↵a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
↵a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
↵a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
↵a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
↵a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
↵a=maxptime:60
↵a=ssrc:885316323 cname:joI6MrZklmLX+lvZ
↵a=ssrc:885316323 msid:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG a7565e73-846b-495a-b50a-42aff6d70d06
↵a=ssrc:885316323 mslabel:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG
↵a=ssrc:885316323 label:a7565e73-846b-495a-b50a-42aff6d70d06
↵m=video 9 RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:9XgGQPNJQUYrwuC3
↵a=ice-pwd:7Y30gM1zjN0Vnt5y6IoOoNYD
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 99:E8:0A:BB:55:9A:5F:C6:21:01:06:32:4B:5A:5E:B7:F0:A7:87:49:68:0A:20:4E:5C:AA:ED:66:87:6E:A3:AB
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:video
↵a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
↵a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
↵a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
↵a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
↵a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
↵a=fmtp:96 apt=100
↵a=ssrc-group:FID 3499157865 1266786744
↵a=ssrc:3499157865 cname:joI6MrZklmLX+lvZ
↵a=ssrc:3499157865 msid:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG c62982b1-d511-4e38-99dc-f212c2f334bc
↵a=ssrc:3499157865 mslabel:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG
↵a=ssrc:3499157865 label:c62982b1-d511-4e38-99dc-f212c2f334bc
↵a=ssrc:1266786744 cname:joI6MrZklmLX+lvZ
↵a=ssrc:1266786744 msid:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG c62982b1-d511-4e38-99dc-f212c2f334bc
↵a=ssrc:1266786744 mslabel:nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG
↵a=ssrc:1266786744 label:c62982b1-d511-4e38-99dc-f212c2f334bc
↵"type: "offer"__proto__: RTCSessionDescriptionoutgoingStream: MediaStreamactive: trueended: falseid: "nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG"label: "nMB73xPU5jOnbz5Aek3wP4ASqlrk2Vl3cgHG"onactive: nullonaddtrack: nullonended: nulloninactive: nullonremovetrack: null__proto__: MediaStreamoutgoingStreamURL: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A63342/72a45df9-ae1f-4098-b7e3-743589f5cc74"pcMap: ObjectproxyUrl: "audio:ISAC/0.0.0.0/0/81.19.110.135:23526"sdpAnswerBuffer: ObjectsdpMap: Objectsinch: fPAPI: Object_appKey: "appKey"_appSecret: undefined_autoStartMxp: true_customStream: undefined_expiresIn: 86400_logHandler: (message) {_logMxpHandler: (){}_multiCall: true_onlineCapability: true_sessionId: "91cf12c2-2b03-47f9-b02f-1ebcdfb97e04"_sessionSecret: "M1sdRn5z2UCTYVMGrAc6FQ=="_subInstanceId: 2586157107_supportVideo: true_url: ObjectapplicationKey: "appKey"authenticate: () { [native code] }authenticateNumber: () { [native code] }authenticateUsername: () { [native code] }callClient: icallData: () { [native code] }callPSTN: () { [native code] }callReporting: () { [native code] }capabilities: ObjectchangePassword: () { [native code] }confirmUserSMS: () { [native code] }createUser: () { [native code] }firefox: falsegetConfiguration: () { [native code] }getInstance: () { [native code] }getInstances: () { [native code] }getServerTime: () { [native code] }getTransportById: () { [native code] }getTransportByParticipants: () { [native code] }getUserProfile: () { [native code] }messageReporting: () { [native code] }mxp: ppostMedia: () { [native code] }pushMessage: () { [native code] }renewInstance: () { [native code] }renewSecret: () { [native code] }started: truetimeDelta: -252updateUser: () { [native code] }user: nverifyUserSMS: () { [native code] }__proto__: ftimeEnded: Thu Jul 02 2015 22:08:18 GMT-0400 (AST)__proto__: Invalid DatetimeEstablished: nulltimeProgressing: nulltoId: "brenty"videoSupport: truewebRtcConfig: ObjecticeServers: Array[2]0: Objecturl: "stun:23.21.150.121"__proto__: Object1: Objectlength: 2__proto__: Array[0]__proto__: Object__proto__: gprogress: 0__proto__: Notification
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Can not hang up call at this time. Will try again in 0.5 seconds (max five retries).", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Can not hang up call at this time. Will try again in 0.5 seconds (max five retries).", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Can not hang up call at this time. Will try again in 0.5 seconds (max five retries).", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Can not hang up call at this time. Will try again in 0.5 seconds (max five retries).", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Can not hang up call at this time. Will try again in 0.5 seconds (max five retries).", object: undefined}
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Call HANGUP Received", object: undefined}
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
TIMEOUT
MXPLog {message: "Added meta data to MXP message", object: q}message: "Added meta data to MXP message"object: q__proto__: MXPLog
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at p.17.p.identifyEnKey (sinch.min.js:6)
    at d (sinch.min.js:4)
    at 8.p.then.l.nextTick.h.promiseDispatch.j (sinch.min.js:4)
    at p.8.d.promiseDispatch (sinch.min.js:4)
    at sinch.min.js:4
    at Array.a (sinch.min.js:4)
    at d (sinch.min.js:4)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    at p.17.p.identifyEnKey (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:6:27539)
    at d (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:9844)
    at 8.p.then.l.nextTick.h.promiseDispatch.j (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:10117)
    at p.8.d.promiseDispatch (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:4377)
    at http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:3382
    at Array.a (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:7540)
    at d (http://localhost:63342/chatome/www/lib/sinch-rtc/sinch.min.js:4:836)
Notification {progress: 0, message: "Successfully initiated call, waiting for MXP signalling.", object: Object}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the API call to initiate the data-call does not seem to have been properly made, it may be due to the way you've integrated the SDK, a bug in the SDK or other issue. Does the sample apps (supplied with the SDK) work with your application key in your environment?

Also, could you make sure (by looking at the "networks" tab in chrome while making a call) that the request for initiating the call is properly made and there's no error.

If you can, could you share more details on your setup and/or code?

*Edit: I'm looking for a request like this;*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was also receiving the console message `Notification {progress: 0, message: "Will retrieve new Mic for stream", object: undefined}` After struggling with this for some time, I found a solution that solved it for me. Basically, Sinch requires HTML5 audio elements to be present on the page. Look in your `onCallProgressing` and `onCallEstablished` event handlers and you'll see lines that look like this:

```
'onCallProgressing': function (TheSinchCall) {

    $('#SinchRingtone').trigger("play");
},

'onCallEstablished': function (TheSinchCall) {

    $('#SinchIncoming').attr('src', TheSinchCall['incomingStreamURL']);
    $('#SinchRingtone').trigger('pause');
},
```

When `$('#SinchRingtone')` and `$('#SinchIncoming')` don't return a jQuery element because the HTML tags aren't on the page, then Sinch won't work.